# Magento 2.3 - How to call html file instead of exception?

Tags: magento2, php, exception

I want to call the `HTML` file in this function. Currently, it is showing exception but I want custom HTML design to display.

```
Magento/vendor/magento/framework/app/bootstrap.php

   if ($isOn && !$isExpected) {
      $this->errorCode = self::ERR_MAINTENANCE;
      echo "<h1>Hello<h1/>";
                throw new \Exception('Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. ');
            }
```

Comment: Is "Hello" showing or not?

Comment: Yes, it is showing hello. but my requirement to call HTML file here in which I do all my designing part.

Comment: I think its better to create a custom theme to achieve this [link]https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/error-page-customization/